# Open browser hitting url and want to get back to flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, stack-overflow

I need to open a url on the browser and user would do something and then i should return back to the app.
also i should come back to the related page according to what user has done on the web.
Thank You in advance.

I tried url_launcher for launch url but after that i dont know how to get back into my app.

Comment: You can use deeplinking for that purpose where you open a certain url which is registered in the app so that app can be opened and in that certain url, you can add add some query params also which you can get in the application and then do the navigation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_app_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin for that purpose,

It provides you with the following widget and a callback of `onUpdateVisitedHistory`, this callback can help you to achieve what you're looking for.

This callback gives you all the URLs user is visiting inside of the in app-browser, if user goes to page of success then the URL of that page should contain "success", when it does, you can close the in-app-browser and send him back to some flutter screen.

```
           InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: Uri.parse(yourLinkHere), // <-- your link
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) => webViewController = controller,
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: onPageChange, // <-- user browser page changes callback
           ),
```

Here is the onPageChange method:

```
void onPageChange(_, Uri? uri, __) {
    url = uri.toString();
    if (url.contains('success')) {
      //close browser using navigator pop and send him to some flutter screen
    } else if (url.contains('cancelled')) {
      //close browser using navigator pop and send him to some flutter screen
    }
  }
```